# Retrive contents as files from everpad when sync doesn't work

Tags: hidden-files, evernote

How can i retrieve all the contents from everpad to use in another user, syncing is not working though it says it have synced.

Edit: After another wrong decision, now i can't access the contents as i have revoked access to my evernote account :(

Answer (score 0):

Try: Copying the following folder into the second user account

```
/home/username/.everpad
```